# Error 1064 in the group by, is my subquery syntax correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I keep having error 1064 in the group by? Is this syntax correct and in accordance with this in the subquery?

```
SELECT dat.a + 10 AS b FROM (SELECT 1 AS a) AS dat
```

```
SELECT `account`.`company`,`account`.`name`, `inventory`.`sellernum`,
ROUND(AVG(`v_winning_clerks`.`sellprice`),2) / (`average appraised price`) AS `average ratio`
FROM `v_winning_clerks`, (SELECT ROUND(AVG(inventory.appraisedprice * IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,3,IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH AND NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,2, 1))), 2) AS `average appraised price`
JOIN `inventory` USING(`itemnum`, `auctionnum`)
JOIN `attendance` USING(`auctionnum`, `sellernum`)
JOIN `account` USING(`accountnum`)
GROUP BY `inventory`.`sellernum`
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the `SELECT` columns.  That is the cause of the error.

Comment: How come? I have `inventory`.`sellernum` in both